# How much of No Time to Die is actually shot in ScreenX format?

Tags: james-bond, no-time-to-die

My local cinema has a couple of [ScreenX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ScreenX) theaters where No Time to Die is showing.

But [this article](https://www.presse-nachrichten.de/2021/09/30/no-time-to-die-wird-erstmals-im-visuell-beeindruckenden-270-grad-panorama-screenx-gezeigt/) says that only some parts of the film extend to the side walls:

> "No Time To Die" in ScreenX will extend specially selected sequences of the film to the left and right side walls of the theater, surrounding viewers with expanded images that naturally fill their peripheral vision. CJ 4DPLEX worked closely with MGM Studios, Eon Productions and the filmmakers to ensure the best possible quality of the film and select key scenes and exclusive footage for the ScreenX versions.

Before paying the price premium, I'd like to know what I'm getting.

Is there a way to know what percentage of the film actually takes advantage of the ScreenX format?

Comment: @Paulie_D May I ask why you deleted that tag?

Comment: There are no other questions associated with it. If/when there are more questions related to ScreenX's technology and films that use it, then perhaps creating a tag to be able to filter on would be useful. Also, if you're going to create a new tag, please fill out the Usage Guidance and Full Tag Wiki fields. The fact that there are tags without those filled out doesn't mean they don't all need to be updated. That is part of community curation of Stack Exchange.

Comment: I really get the feeling this is "this year's 3D". 3D peaked between 2010 & 2014 & has been tailing off ever since. Anybody old enough to remember "Sensurround" ? ;)

Comment: While I can't quantify it, I can say that quite a lot of the movie was in the ScreenX format, though not all of it.  At a very rough guess, I would say 75-80% used the side screens.